# Angular universal build breaks with the following error: throw Error("not supported");

Tags: node.js, linux, angular-universal

Running the following command : npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr runs 3 different compilation stages but on the last one it returns the following error resulting to the server not starting.

```
Error: not supported
at Root.loadSync (/var/www/html/stage/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:234:15)
at Object.loadSync (/var/www/html/stage/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/index-light.js:69:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/stage/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:244:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Environment and packages"

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 11.6.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, platform-webworker
... platform-webworker-dynamic, router, service-worker
```

My server.ts looks as follows

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,   join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser/index.html'))).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
global['document'] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
```

Comment: Some of your code (or another lib) is probably calling some navigator function that not supported in domino. You have no choice but to debug and try to find out where it's happening

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem.

```
1. Deleted problematic folder ./node_modules/@grpc/...
2. Manually uploaded a new @grpc folder with
   @grpc
   -- proto-loader
   ---- build/src/index.js
   ---- LICENCE
   ---- package.json
```

here's the repo to those who may find it useful
--> https://github.com/Gerald34/Angular-Universal-grpc

Answer (score 0):

you can fix by adding process to your fake window in the server.ts file

`win.process = process;`

You can find more info in this article, with also other errors I encountered with Angular SSR + Firebase